# How to rewrite multi-level match expression

Tags: f#

I have functions which returns `a' option` type.  And I have functions which looks like:

```
let foo(a) = 
   match fooB a.F1 with
   | Some(b) -> match fooC b.F2 with
                | Some(c) -> match fooD c.F3 with 
                             | Some(d) -> match fooE d.F4 with 
                                          // ......
                             | None -> ()
                | None -> ()
    | None -> ()
```

Is there any functional pattern to avoid this multilevel `match expressions` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like what you're looking for is `Option.bind`:

```
let foo(a) = 
    fooB a.F1 
    |> Option.bind(fun b -> fooC b.F2)
    |> Option.bind(fun c -> fooD c.F3)
    |> Option.bind(fun d -> fooE d.F4)
```

`Option.bind` is basically equivalent to

```
// ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a option -> 'b option
let bind f m =
    match m with
    | Some x -> f x
    | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 4):

Functional programming may leverage monadic operations, specifically the `bind` operator. Here is an illustration of its use on the [Maybe monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad), which is from Haskell but does the same as F#'s `Option` type.

Luckily, the `bind` operator is almost predefined:

```
let (>>=) ma f = Option.bind f ma

let foo a = 
    fooB a.F1
    >>= fun b -> fooC b.F2 
    >>= fun c -> fooD c.F3 
    >>= fun d -> fooE d.F4
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create an Computation Expression Builder for the Option type, leveraging the `Option.bind` function.

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member __.Bind (opt,map) = Option.bind map opt
    member __.Return value = Some value
    member __.ReturnFrom (opt: Option<_>) = opt
    member __.Zero () = Some ()

let option = OptionBuilder()
```

Then, you can do all of your work in one `option` computation:

```
let foo a =
    option {
        let! b = fooB a.F1
        let! c = fooC b.F2
        let! d = fooD c.F3
        return! fooE d.F4
    }
```

This will return `Some` of `d.F4` if all the Options are `Some`, otherwise it will return `None`.